# oracle sql get multiple rows want to set into one single row

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I get the following error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

SQL:

```
SELECT t.test 
FROM device t 
JOIN device_interface v on t.pe = v.end_test 
WHERE v.test = upper('IE5656') and t.device_type like '%tin%'
```

Output:

```
T.TEST:
XEM5454
XEM7646
```

I would like to display it like this in order to not get an error :

```
T.TEST:
XEM5454 | XEM7646
```

OR

```
T.TEST:
XEM5454, XEM7646
```

What need to be consider into the sql in order to display it like the example above?

Thank yo uso much for your help and support.

Comment: `LISTAGG` is the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Input -

```
CREATE TABLE tabl1
    (COL1 varchar2(7))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO tabl1 (COL1)
         VALUES ('XEM5454')
    INTO tabl1 (COL1)
         VALUES ('XEM7646')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

> Query -

```
select listagg(col1,',')WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col1) as value
FROM tabl1;
```

> Output -

```
VALUE
XEM5454,XEM7646
```